# Изменить файл формата .txt используя цикл в паре с список C#

Tags: c#

Код написанный с запросом SQL работает так как нужно, но как только дело дошло до цикла, сразу появилась ошибка с сообщением

> IndexOutOfRangeExeption. Индекс находился вне границ массива.

Да и файл не изменился, нужные строки не удалились. Как сделать что бы не было данного исключения и файл изменялся, а точнее удалял строки который содержит отдельный список?

---

```
var domain = new List<string>();
// MYSQL
string serverName = "";
string userName = "s";
string dbName = "";
string port = "";
string password = "";
string connStr = "server=" + serverName + ";user=" + userName + ";database=" + dbName + ";port=" + port + ";password=" + password + ";SslMode=none;";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
string sql = "SELECT * FROM domain";
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
conn.Open();
MySqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
    domain.Add(reader.GetString(0));
conn.Close();
//MySQL Ends

string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(pathFile, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));//Массив строк который получает строки из файла, который нужно изменить
for (int i = 0; i < countline; i++ )//Цикл , который при каждом повторении проверяет что бы файл не содержал строки по индексу литерала цикла.
{
    var re = File.ReadAllLines(pathFile, Encoding.Default).Where(s => !s.Contains(domain[i]));//изменение файла
 File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", re, Encoding.Default);//Перезапись файла
}
```

Comment: Что вы пробовали сделать, что у вас не получается? Покажите ваш код в вопросе.

Comment: Загружаете файл в List<string> с помощью StreamReader, редактируете и записываете обратно через StreamWriter

Comment: @win8de все то что написали в комментариях, разместите в вопросе!

Comment: А почему `.Where(s => !s.Contains(domain[i])`

Comment: @SeeSharp как правильнее будет?

Comment: Были бы коментарии...

Comment: Что за ошибка, какое сообщение?

Comment: @SeeSharp System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции.
Имя параметра: index"

Comment: У вас `domain` список инициализорован, а записей в нём нет. Вот и получаете ошибку `OutOfRange` потому, что в пустом списке индексов нет.

Comment: Пробуйте, уважаемый

Comment: @SeeSharp обновил код

Comment: `file.txt` это сам файл?

Comment: Куда сохраняет результаты, а pathFile - это директория того файла, из которого нужно отсеять массив слов

Comment: Обновил ответ. проверяйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ошибка** в том что нужно использовать в [цикле **for**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ch45axte(v=vs.120).aspx) (точнее говоря в его условии выполнения) длину массива или списка как в Вашем случае.

Вторая проблема в том, что при сохранении файла вы указали его название, но не путь. Поэтому файл сохранился скорее всего в корневую папку проекта *(это не точно)*

```
var pathFile = @"D:\ВЛАД\test.txt";//Тут Ваш путь файла который нужно отсеять
var newpath = @"path\newfile.txt";//Тут путь куда нужно отсеянный файл сохранить 
var domain = new List<string>  //Список со строками которых быть не должно
{
    "get",    //Добавил для примера
    "try"
}; 
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(pathFile);//Файл изначально
    foreach (var item in domain)
    {
        allLines = File.ReadAllLines(pathFile, Encoding.Default).Where(s => !s.Contains(item));

    }
    File.WriteAllLines(newpath, allLines, Encoding.Default);
}
```

И советую Вам научиться пользоваться **отладчиком**, без которого в программировании туго будет. Подробнее о данной сущности [**здесь**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx).

Comment: Cпасибо, помог очень)

Comment: Репутации не хватает, для +1

Comment: Плюсанул, + сократил код, добавив упрощенный конструктор `List<>`.

Comment: Спасибо, правки мелкие спешил человеку помочь.

Comment: Для `List` кстати можно использовать `foreach (var element in domain)` вместо `for` и `!s.Contains(element)`, чтобы не мучатся с индексами.

Comment: Кстати да. Сейчас правлю

Comment: Правил. Теперь думаю всё идеально

Comment: Хотя рефракторинг дело тонкое. Тут у каждого свой подход. Только если не индус.

Comment: Еще один момент, у вас будет несколько перезаписей файла. Мне кажется лучше было бы прочитать файл, потом из полученной коллекции убрать все строки из domain, и уже потом записать файл.

Comment: @SeeSharp не работает var, показывает ошибку http://prntscr.com/kkoy45

Comment: @win8de секунду щас у себя запущу

Comment: @win8de вы измените строку с ошибкой на вот эту `re = File.ReadAllLines(pathFile, Encoding.Default).Where(s => !s.Contains(item)).ToArray();`

Comment: Исправили бы хоть код. У вас ошибка на ошибке. allLines читаете, хотя потом не используете, в foreach переменную re вы вообще каждый раз перезаписываете, так что в конце остаётся только вариант с последним элементом в domain.

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще так:

```
var pathFile = @"D:\ВЛАД\test.txt";//Тут Ваш путь файла который нужно отсеять
var newpath = @"path\newfile.txt";//Тут путь куда нужно отсеянный файл сохранить 
var domain = new List<string>  //Список с строками которых быть не должно
{
    "try"
};
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(pathFile); //Файл изначально
var output = new List<string>();

foreach (var line in allLines)
{
    if (!domain.Contains(line)) 
    {
        output.Add(line);
    }
}
File.WriteAllLines(newpath, output, Encoding.Default);
```

Идея похожа на [более ранний ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/868139/218976), с той лишь разницей что цикл по строкам исходного файла.

---

А можно вообще обойтись без цикла:

```
var pathFile = @"D:\ВЛАД\test.txt";//Тут Ваш путь файла который нужно отсеять
var newpath = @"path\newfile.txt";//Тут путь куда нужно отсеянный файл сохранить 
var domain = new List<string>  //Список с строками которых быть не должно
{
    "try"
};
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(pathFile);  //Файл изначально  
var list = allLines.AsEnumerable().Where(x => !domain.Contains(x)).ToList();

File.WriteAllLines(newpath, list, Encoding.Default);
```